Intuition behind the definition(s) of a convex function
I am studying for future math imo olympiads and came across in the compendium for the definition of a convex function

Definition 2.22. A real function f defined on an interval I is convex if $f(\alpha x+ \beta y) ≤ \alpha f(x) + \beta f(y)$. for all x, y ∈ I and all $\alpha, \beta > 0$ such that $\alpha + \beta = 1$.
A function f is said to be concave if the opposite inequality holds, i.e., if -f is convex,

Later, they prove that the second derivative of such function is nondecreasing.

Theorem 2.24. If f is differentiable, then it is convex if and only if the derivative f' is nondecreasing. Similarly, differentiable function f is concave if and only if f' is nonincreasing.

The well known (at least for me, and from what can be deducted from the shape of a convex function) definition is that the derivative is nondecreasing (the above theorem) , why is it that they use this definition? How is it related to the fact that the second derivative is nondecreasing? And why would they choose to use such a messy definition instead of defining the  second derivative to be nondecreasing?
In conclusion, how is the above definition related to my known 'definition' of a convex function using the second derivative, and what's better and more accurate about this definition?

Not every function is differentiable.

The first definition does not have any differentiability requirement on the function $f$ and hence is the most general definition of a convex function. If the function is differentiable, then the definition 2.22 is equivalent to saying that $f'$ is nondecreasing. If the function $f$ is twice differentiable, then the definition becomes equivalent to $f'' \geq 0$. All the equivalences are rather straightforward to show. It is a good exercise to try to prove them.

The epigraph of a function is the region above the graph. A function is convex if the epigraph is a convex set.  A supporting line is a line that touches the graph at at least one point and lies below the graph. A function is convex if every point on the graph has a supporting line touching it. If the function is differentiable at a point , the supporting line is unique and I equal to the tangent line. These are the fundamental definitions of a convex function because they describe clearly how a convex function is related to a linear approximation.

Mathematicians often identify a useful property, make it as abstract as possible, and then present that as the definition without mention of why it was envisioned to be useful in the first place. It's a frustrating pattern that you have to learn to identify.

Look for "Functions of one variable" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function. A function is convex iff its epigraph is convex.

Consider accepting an answer if it answers your question

A more intuitive way to interpret convex functions using the definition from a convex shape.

For every two points inside the shape, draw a line between them. If the entire line is always fully inside the shape, the shape is convex. Now let's apply this idea to a convex function.
Take two points above the curve, make a line between them, if the entire line always stays above, then the function is convex. Hopefully you see the parallel.
The second derivative always needs to be nonnegative as if it was negative at any point we could find a concave region.

Now back to this definition:

Definition 2.22. A real function $f$ defined on an interval $I$ is convex if $f(\alpha x+ \beta y) \leq \alpha f(x)+ \beta f(y)$. for all $x, y \in I$ and all $\alpha, \beta >0$
such that $\alpha+\beta=1$.

The right-hand side of this equation is saying: The straightline between between any two points $\alpha f(x)+ \beta f(y)$ is always above the curve $f(\alpha x+ \beta y)$

There are many results that hold true for convex functions that are not differentiable (for example, in the field of numerical optimisation or numerical solving of nonlinear equations), so the first definition is way more general than the one with the derivative.
However, when the function is differentiable, both definitions are equivalent.

Suppose that $f$ is convex (respectively concave) function on the interval $I=[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$, $a<b$. The definition of $f$ being convex (resp. concave) on $I$ simply means that every point $(x,f(x))$ lies below (resp. above) point $(x,g(x))$, where $g$ is the straight line connecting the two points $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$. In other words, we can state that the graph of $f$, $G(f):=\{(x,f(x))\in\mathbb{R}^2:x\in I\}$, lies below (resp. above) the graph of $g$. Without loss of generality, consider the case for which $f$ is convex (the other case is treated analogously). For any fixed $x\in I$, the condition “point $(x,f(x))$ lies below point $(x,g(x))$” translates mathematically to:
$$ f(x)\leq g(x) $$
(since $x$ is the same for both points). However, this condition is usually expressed with a parameterization of $x$ which becomes a function $x(t)$ of a parameter $t\in T$, where $T\subset\mathbb{R}$ is the parameter set. If we let $t\in[0,1]$ such that $x(0)=a$ and $x(1)=b$ we find the parameterisation:
$$ x(t)=(1-t)a+tb. $$
Then, we can find the parameterisation of the line $g(t)=g(x(t))$. Since:
$$ g(x)= \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-a)+f(a) =\dots= \frac{x-a}{b-a}f(b)+\frac{b-x}{b-a}f(a), $$
it follows that
$$ g(t)=(1-t)f(a)+tf(b). $$
The condition of convexity is then expressed as:
$$ f(x(t))\leq g(x(t)), \\
f((1-t)a+tb)\leq (1-t)f(a)+tf(b), $$
for every $t\in[0,1]$. To be consistent with the notations used in your material, if you define $\alpha,\beta\in[0,1]$ as $\beta:= t$ and $\alpha:=1-t$ you find the equivalent form:
$$ f(\alpha a+\beta b)\leq\alpha f(a)+\beta f(b), $$
for any $\alpha,\beta\in[0,1]$ such that $\alpha+\beta=1$.
All this being said, it’s now possible to relate this definition with an equivalent one which takes into account the derivative $f’$ of the function whenever $f’$ exists on $I$, meaning that $f$ must be differentiable on $I$. Consider two points $a<x_1<x_2<b$.Then, the parameterisation of any point $x_1<x<x_2$ becomes:
$$ x(t)=(1-t)x_1+tx_2. $$
It follows that the condition of convexity transforms into:
$$ f((1-t)x_1+tx_2)\leq (1-t)f(x_1)+tf(x_2). $$
By doing few manipulations, from the former equation it is found that:
$$ \frac{f(x(t))-f(x_1)}{x(t)-x_1}\leq\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}\text{ and }\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}\leq \frac{f(x(t))-f(x_2)}{x(t)-x_2}, $$
which combined give:
$$
\frac{f(x(t))-f(x_1)}{x(t)-x_1}\leq\frac{f(x(t))-f(x_2)}{x(t)-x_2}.
$$
Finally, taking the limits as $t\to 0$ (which implies $x(t)\to x_1) and as $t\to 1$ (which implies $x(t)\to x_2$) it’s found that:
$$ \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(x(t))-f(x_1)}{x(t)-x_1}\leq\lim_{t\to 1} \frac{f(x(t))-f(x_2)}{x(t)-x_2} $$
(limit preserves inequality). In conclusion, if and only if the function $f$ is differentiable, we can state that:
$$f’(x_1)\leq f’(x_2), $$
which is equivalent of saying that $f’$ is increasing.
